# Merging 2 Text Files in C#

Tags: c#, file, merge

Firstly, i'd just like to mention that I've only started learning C# a few days ago so my knowledge of it is limited.

I'm trying to create a program that will parse text files for certain phrases input by the user and then output them into a new text document.

At the moment, i have it the program searching the original input file and gathering the selected text input by the user, coping those lines out, creating new text files and then merging them together and also deleting them afterwards.

I'm guessing that this is not the most efficient way of creating this but i just created it and had it work in a logical manor for me to understand as a novice.

The code is as follows;

```
private void TextInput1()
    {
        using (StreamReader fileOpen = new StreamReader(txtInput.Text))
        {
            using (StreamWriter fileWrite = new StreamWriter(@"*DIRECTORY*\FIRSTFILE.txt"))
            {
                string file;
                while ((file = fileOpen.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (file.Contains(txtFind.Text))
                    {
                            fileWrite.Write(file + "\r\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void TextInput2()
    {
        using (StreamReader fileOpen = new StreamReader(txtInput.Text))
        {
            using (StreamWriter fileWrite = new StreamWriter(@"*DIRECTORY*\SECONDFILE.txt"))
            {
                string file;
                while ((file = fileOpen.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (file.Contains(txtFind2.Text))
                    {
                        fileWrite.Write("\r\n" + file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Combination()
    {
        ArrayList fileArray = new ArrayList();

        using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(@"*DIRECTORY*\FINALOUTPUT.txt"))
        {

            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"*DIRECTORY*\FIRSTFILE.txt"))
            {
                writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }

            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"*DIRECTORY*\SECONDFILE.txt"))
            {
                writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }

    }

    private static void Delete()
    {
        if (File.Exists(@"*DIRECTORY*\FIRSTFILE.txt"))
            {
                File.Delete(@"*DIRECTORY*\FIRSTFILE.txt");
            }

        if (File.Exists(@"*DIRECTORY*\SECONDFILE.txt"))
            {
                 File.Delete(@"*DIRECTORY*\SECONDFILE.txt");
            }

    }
```

The output file that is being created is simply outputting the first text input followed by the second. I am wondering if it is possible to be able to merge them into 1 file, 1 line at a time as it is a consecutive file meaning have the information from Input 1 followed 2 is needed rather than all of 1 then all of 2.

Thanks, Neil.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you want to write on line from the first file followed by one line from the second file and so on. Right?

Comment: You might want to make your question more clear, because from the answers given, I would think, that **I** understand your wish differently. Do you want: Reading from both files in parallel and doing the output in parallel into a single file WITHOUT the need to `merge` two different output files? This is possible (and not TOO difficult), though you might consider that reading from 2 files (which are on the same harddrive) in parallel is usually not 2 times faster than reading 2 files sequentially. If you are unlucky it will be much slower.

Comment: I'm sorry if i didn't make it clear. @Steve has the correct idea. After the 2 files are created, merge them 1 line at a time meaning, I.E. Line 1 - File 1, Line 1 - File 2, Line 2 - File 1, Line 2 - File 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To combine the two files content in an one merged file line by line you could substitute your Combination() code with this

```
string[] file1 = File.ReadAllLines("*DIRECTORY*\FIRSTFILE.txt");
string[] file2 = File.ReadAllLines("*DIRECTORY*\SECONDFILE.txt");

using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(@"*DIRECTORY*\FINALOUTPUT.txt"))
{
    int lineNum = 0;
    while(lineNum < file1.Length || lineNum < file2.Length)
    {
        if(lineNum < file1.Length)
            writer.WriteLine(file1[lineNum]);
        if(lineNum < file2.Length)
            writer.WriteLine(file2[lineNum]);
        lineNum++;
    }
}
```

This assumes that the two files don't contains the same number of lines.

Comment: that code worked perfectly, that you very much Steve, works like a charm.

Comment: Performance would be hit, since you reading all data into string.. instead, you can create the copy of first file then append second file in to it instead of keeping two file data into memory, you have to keep for only one

Answer (score 6):

try this method. You can receive three paths. File 1, File 2 and File output.

```
public void MergeFiles(string pathFile1, string pathFile2, string pathResult)
{
    File.WriteAllText(pathResult, File.ReadAllText(pathFile1) + File.ReadAllText(pathFile2));
}
```

If the `pathResult` file exists, the `WriteAllText` method will overwrite it. Remember to include `System.IO` namespace.

Important: It is not recommended for large files! Use another options available on this thread.

Comment: For very large files you would use 1 x `WriteAlltext()` and then the other(s) with `AppendAlltext()`

Comment: Henk, thank you for the tip. For very large files, would be a nice pratice to load all content in a StringBuilder and output with 1x `WriteAllText` method?

Comment: No, a StringBuilder would have (almost) the same memory pressure.

Answer (score 2):

If your input files are quite large and you run out of memory, you could also try wrapping the two readers like this:

```
        using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(@"*DIRECTORY*\FINALOUTPUT.txt"))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader1 = File.OpenText(@"*DIRECTORY*\FIRSTFILE.txt"))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader2 = File.OpenText(@"*DIRECTORY*\SECONDFILE.txt"))
                {
                    string line1 = null;
                    string line2 = null;
                    while ((line1 = reader1.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(line1);
                        line2 = reader2.ReadLine();
                        if(line2 != null)
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(line2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Still, you have to have an idea how many lines you have in your input files, but I think it gives you the general idea to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `FileInfo` extension you could merge one or more files by doing the following:

```
public static class FileInfoExtensions
{
  public static void MergeFiles(this FileInfo fi, string strOutputPath , params string[] filesToMerge)
  {
    var fiLines = File.ReadAllLines(fi.FullName).ToList();
    fiLines.AddRange(filesToMerge.SelectMany(file => File.ReadAllLines(file)));
    File.WriteAllLines(strOutputPath, fiLines.ToArray());
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
  FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("input");
  fi.MergeFiles("output", "File2", "File3");
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this question is almost old enough to (up)vote (itself), but for an extensible approach:

```
const string FileMergeDivider = "\n\n";

public void MergeFiles(string outputPath, params string[] inputPaths)
{
    if (!inputPaths.Any())
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(inputPaths) + " required");

    if (inputPaths.Any(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace) || !inputPaths.All(File.Exists))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputPaths), "contains invalid path(s)");

    File.WriteAllText(outputPath, string.Join(FileMergeDivider, inputPaths.Select(File.ReadAllText)));
}
```