# How to merge two text (.txt) file into single one and distinct the same content?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file-io

I have `text1.txt` and have the content as per below:

```
longitude,latt,u,70772,xxxx
31, 121, -10.2
31, 122, -20.9
31, 123, 40.8
.
.
44, 131, -44.1
```

I have `text2.txt` and have the content as per below:

```
longitude,latt,v,70772,xxxx
31, 121, 12.1
31, 122, 32.4
31, 123, -2.5
.
.
44, 131, 7.3
```

As you can see, `text1.txt` and `text2.txt` share some same commonality.

1st common: the first line of each text file should be skipped, because contain non important information

2nd common: each text file contain the same longitude and lattidue value, which is

```
31 , 121 , x
31 , 122 , x
31 , 123 , x
.
.
44 , 131 , x
```

my objective is to combine `text1.txt` and `text2.txt` into `result.txt` and have the following result:

```
31, 121, -10.2, 12.1
31, 121, -20.9, 32.4
31, 123, 40.8, -2.5
.
.
44, 131, -44.1, 7.3
```

Referring to this source [MergeTwoTextFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839669/merging-2-text-files-in-c-sharp) I already know how to merge two text file. But what I do not know is, how to merge two text file with some specific condition.

I hope can do something like `concat` and `distict`, any idea?

**Update:** 3 UI buttons

[image]

Code for open file button

```
private void toolStripBtnOpenV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        toolStripBtnOpenV.Enabled = false;

        openFileDialog1.FileName = "";

        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;

        v_filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        if (toolStripBtnOpenU.Enabled == false)
        {
            toolStripBtnMerge.Enabled = true;
        }
}
```

Inside MergeUV button_click event, do like what SamiHuutoniemi suggested, except change the first line like this:

```
List<string> filelist = new List<string>() { v_filePath , u_filePath };
```

It will takes minimun 20 minutes to write the output file if your file size is >5MB

Comment: I hope I can try. I will update some sample code when get back to office. Post the question first, is just to get some idea on doing it

Answer (score 2):

You could read both textfiles, save the data as lists of `Tuple<int, int, List<double>>` (where you have the tuples "unique" in that sense that there are no two tuples sharing the two ints). Then output a textfile into which you print all the Tuples in your format.

This accomplishes what I think you want to do.

```
List<string> filelist = new List<string>() { "text1.txt", "text2.txt" };
List<Tuple<int, int, List<double>>> dataList = new List<Tuple<int, int, List<double>>>();

foreach (var file in filelist)
{
    string line;
    using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        tr.ReadLine();  //skip header
        while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var tokens = line.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int longitude = int.Parse(tokens[0]);
            int latitude = int.Parse(tokens[1]);
            double value = double.Parse(tokens[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            Tuple<int, int, List<double>> t = dataList.Where(x => (int)x.Item1 == longitude && (int)x.Item2 == latitude).FirstOrDefault();
            if (t == null)
            {
                dataList.Add(new Tuple<int, int, List<double>>(longitude, latitude, new List<double>() { value }));
            }
            else
            {
                t.Item3.Add(value);
            }
        }
    }
}

using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("output.txt"))
{
    foreach (var t in dataList)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0}, {1}, ", t.Item1, t.Item2));
        foreach (var value in t.Item3)
        {
            sb.Append(String.Format("{0}, ", value));
        }

        tw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I just trying out this solution. Match perfectly with my requirement. However, I have >20, 000 lines inside my `text1.txt` and `text2.txt`, it takes too much time for it to complete the `tr.ReadLine` :(

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
var file1 = File.ReadAllLines("path1");
var file2 = File.ReadAllLines("path2");

var result = new List<string>();

//Skip line 0
for (int i = 1; i < file1.Length; i++)
{
    //Get the values from each correseponding file
    var file1Values  = file1[i].Split(',').Select(v => v.Trim());
    var file2Values  = file2[i].Split(',').Select(v => v.Trim());

    //Get distinct values & join
    result.Add(string.Join(",", file1Values.Union(file2Values)));
}

File.WriteAllLines("resultpath", result);
```

Comment: I suspect that the line you claim is getting distinct does no such thing.  But otherwise, it's a good start.

Comment: It doesn't.  The OP wants `31, 121, -10.2, 12.1` for the first line, and you are giving `31,121,-10.2,31,121,12.1`.

Answer (score 0):

To just merge them without the first line of each, you can try this one-liner:

```
File.WriteAllLines("result.txt", File.ReadLines("text1.txt").Skip(1).Concat(File.ReadLines("text2.txt").Skip(1)));
```

If you need them distinct on a pure line-by-line comparison level:

```
File.WriteAllLines("result.txt", File.ReadLines("text1.txt").Skip(1).Concat(File.ReadLines("text2.txt").Skip(1)).Distinct());
```

Comment: this could be what I want. I will update sample code based on this solution.

Comment: He's not asking to add two files onto each other - he's talking about merging line-by-line

Comment: Wow, this solution is good for joining 2 files without duplicated lines. But the OP's want is different. :)